# brew installed apache-spark unable to access s3 files

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, homebrew

After `brew install apache-spark`, `sc.textFile("s3n://...")` in `spark-shell` fails with `java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n`.  This is not the case in `spark-shell` accessed through an EC2 machine launched with `spark-ec2`.  The [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/apache-spark.rb) formula appears to build with a sufficiently late version of Hadoop, and this error is thrown whether or not `brew install hadoop` has been run first.

**How can I install spark with homebrew such that it will be able to read `s3n://` files?**

Comment: This might be a Hadoop-client version error. You might want to take a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 filesystems aren't enabled in Hadoop 2.6 by default.
So Spark versions that built with hadoop2.6 have no any S3-based fs available too. Possible solutions:

- Solution 1. Use Spark built with Hadoop 2.4 (just change file name to "spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz" and update sha256) and s3n:// fs will work.
- Solution 2. Enable s3n:// filesystem.
  Specify the `--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem` option when you start spark-shell.

  Also you should set path to the required libraries: `--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=<path>/* --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=<path>/*` where `<path>` is the directory with `hadoop-aws`, `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4` and `guava-11.0.2` jar's.
- Solution 3. Use newer s3a:// filesystem. It's enabled by default. Path to the required libraries should be set too.

**Note 1:** Options can also be set in conf/spark-defaults.conf file so you don't need to provide them every time with `--conf`, read the [guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties).

**Note 2:** You can point `<path>` to share/hadoop/tools/lib directory in Hadoop 2.6+ distribution (s3a requires libraries from Hadoop 2.7+) or get required libraries from Maven Central ([1](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar), [2](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar), [3](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar)).

**Note 3:** Provide credentials for s3n in environment variables, `~/.aws/config` file or `--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId= --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=`.

s3a requires `--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key= --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=` options (no environment variables or .aws-file).

**Note 4:** s3:// can be set as alias either for s3n (`--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem`) or s3a (`--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`).

Comment: @llya awesome answer.  some follow up q's:  re: Solution 1: would I need to change the fields  `sha256` and `version` in `apache-spark.rb`?  what would that file look like, then?  re:  Note 3 and 4:  how to configure so that this is default behavior, and doesn't need to be specified every time?  thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to change sha256 (read [this comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/6e5d803878b2ea35b2243ce4fa1192e7d3b5e8a8/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb#L1604-L1607)), version would be the same. Updated Note 1 about setting default behaviour.

Comment: good answer! For me it worked using `--jars` instead of `--conf`: `spark-shell --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem --jars=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-aws-2.7.2.jar,/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar,/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar`